# Comma and Bracket Colors in visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, fortran

How Do I Change Comma and Bracket Colors in VS 2022?

I use fortran language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to :
Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors > Display Items : Punctuation
Change the foreground color

Comment: i did it but nothing happened